# Getting LNK2005, I don't see what I can do to fix this

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I omitted `#include "stdafx.h` in each file.

stdafx.h (precompiled headers)

```
#include a.h
#include b.h
class stuff;
stuff * s
```

a.h

```
class thing{float f; void fun()};
```

a.cc

```
void thing::fun(){}
thing::thing():
    f(b->f) {} // lnk 2005 linking error
```

b.h

```
struct stuff
{
    float f;
    thing * t;
};
```

b.cc

```
stuff::stuff(): f(3.4) { t = new thing; }
```

main.cc

```
int main()
{
    s = new stuff;
    s -> fun();
}
```

As you can see, I try to access `s` which is predeclared in stdafx.h

I'm doing this design so I don't have to rely on singletons (I have one main class which I want to access in other smaller objects)

Do i need to use the `extern` keyword in some way ? Is the precompiled header causing problem ?

Comment: Surely you mean `#include "a.h"`

Comment: Please use the clipboard to copy your code into the question  - there's at least one syntax error, and it looks like the line you indicate as being the cause of the error is wrong (I believe it should be `f(s->f) {}`).  These kinds of typos can make it difficult to know what the problem really is, since additional problems are piled on top.

Comment: It's not that exact code, my code project is much larger, I just used this code as example to describe my problem, there's no room here to paste all my project's code.

Comment: @gokoon: the same can be done for repro code used in a question.

Comment: Being a good programmer, you shouldn't just paste C++ pseudo code. Put small, elegant and problematic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by redesigning code. C++ is not very much clean to use.

Answer (score 1):

In stdafx.h, you've declared s, but you've never defined it.  I would:

1. Add `extern` to the declaration in stdafx.h
2. Add a definition of s in main.cc like this:

   stuff * s = NULL;

Comment: Minor detail: you say, "but you've never defined it" - that is incorrect.  It *is* defined, but in the header so it ends up being defined in each translation unit. That's the problem.  Your steps to fix are correct.

Comment: @Michael Burr:  Yes, I misspoke.  If stdafx.h had the `extern`, then my statement would have been correct.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the global variables.  They are dangerous because any task can read and write to it.  In mult-thread and multi-task systems, controlling access to the global variable becomes necessary and more complicated.

In my current project, I have demanded that there be no global variables.  There can be static local variables with getters and setters.  Using getters and setters allows one to slide in patterns to prevent multitasking issues from arising.

Try your best to get rid of a global variable.  You've already found one issue against them.